# If condition in where clause where a operator is required

Tags: sql

I have a select top 1 subquery & the where clause needs to have if a = @a the b<>@b else if a <> @a then b = @b

I'm trying to get a top 1 date from the subquery where it's the first date after the condition of either (a = @a And b <> @b) Or (a <> @a And b = @b).

I've looked at using CASE but that expects a single value if the condition is met, not a statement. I've tried an IF condition..Begin ...End & couldn't get that to work

```
WHERE (T.Competition_Idx = TC.PtsCompID And TC.PtsMale = @histMale And TC.PtsFemale <> @histFemale And TE.StylID = @histStyle) 
                        OR (T.Competition_Idx = TC.PtsCompID And TC.PtsMale <> @histMale And TC.PtsFemale = @histFemale And TE.StylID = @histStyle)
                            ORDER BY T.Comp_Date DESC),@histStartDate)
```

I should get a date where the condition of a = @a And b = @b is not met but I'm getting the date of the last record

Comment: Not sure how to reply on this forum. There could be records where a = 1 and b = 0 then some with a = 1 and b = 2 after which a =1 and b goes back to = 0. I need to get the last date of where a =1 and b = 0. These are partnerships & I only need the records of the latest partneship which is considered a new one when a =1 And b went back to being =0 if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the question has to do with the code.

But the normal logic for optional parameters looks like:

```
where (@a is null or a = @a) or
      (@b is null or b = @b)
```

I'm not sure if that is what you want.  Otherwise, a direct translation of your logic is:

```
where (@a = a and @b <> b) or
      (@a <> a and @b = b)
```